# Consecutive Javascript script tags in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a .jsp file which is outlined below. Note that:

- There are two script tags
- The first script tag has the Javascript type associated with it, the second doesn't
- The second script tag is directly after the first
- The second script tag contains a function that is invoked from inside the first

```
    <div>
        <!--  various bits of HTML and JSTL etc -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        runWhenPageReady() {
            doSomething();
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function doSomething() {
            //do something
        }
    </script>
```

We have one user whose browser doesn't load the page correctly, and the console returns the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined
```

How do browsers evaluate  tags - is the fact that the function is defined in a different `<script>` tag from the first the likely culprit? Are there any problems associated with joining the two `<script>` tags together?

Comment: you don't need a type. it's probably some browser extension messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have expected the error in any browser.

A `<script>` tag is executed after the closing tag is reached. So when the first tag is closed, the function definition has not yet been processed. This should break with "Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined" at the time the function is invoked:

```html
<script>
  foo();
</script>
<script>
  function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
</script>
```

If we reverse the scripts, the function will be defined at the time it is invoked, and everything works:

```html
<script>
  function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
</script>
<script>
  foo();
</script>
```

If we join the scripts together, it will work in either order, since within a single script, `function` will be hoisted to the top:

```html
<script>
  foo();

  function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @dandavis: Where was parse time referenced? EDIT: I see, yes, the error may be intermittent simply because other users don't go down the code branch that invokes the problemantic function.

Comment: well presumably, `runWhenPageReady()` does what it claims ;) and how else would it work for all-1?

Comment: @dandavis Presumably :) Comments and names lie all the time :) Also, it might happen that it is not the only place in the code `doSomething` is invoked. And here's a simple way it would work for all but one: `if (user == "bad_luck_guy") doSomething()` (though I don't believe it is that blatant). You're right though, something fishy is going on.

Comment: fair enough, I can buy all that, but it doesn't quite explain the "sometimes", but i'm not sure we can answer that w/o further info or actual (non-syntax error) code... Maybe the browser is netscape, or some extension (tries to) enforces strict html.

Comment: That said, it would probably be good for OP to check the stack trace and see where the function is invoked from (and at what time). `<script>debugger;</script>` inserted between script tags will let you know if any shenanigans are happening during the 1st script execution (i.e. _not_ when page is ready).